# Flex how to margin button

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- styles/TimeFormat.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" backgroundColor="red">

    <mx:Style>
    Button
    {
        marginLeft: 500px;

    }

    </mx:Style>
    <mx:Button label="Start" />
</mx:Application>
```

the marginLeft doesn't work, how can I move the button somewhere else from the center that is by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to do it in styles and it worked:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" 
            minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<mx:Style>
    Button
    {
        left: 500px;
        top: 20px;
    }
</mx:Style>
<mx:Button label="Hello"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Alternate you can add <mx:Spacer width="500"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move the button, use left or x properties:

```
<mx:Button label="Start" left="500" />
```

Comment: can I write this in the styles?, but the Left and Right don't work in the styles